# android autocompletetextview from multiple items in arraylist

Tags: android, kotlin, autocompletetextview

I am hoping someone can share how do I create an `autoCompleteTextView` that has data comes from an arrayList containing 2 entries.

example of `arrayList`

```
foo[(bar=001, far=sometext1), (bar=002, far=sometext2), (bar=003, far=sometext3), (bar=004, far=sometext4)]
```

What I am trying to achieve is for my `autoCompleteTextView` to be able to search via `001` OR `sometext1`, and it will autocomplete with that item in the dropdown menu.

Currently, the below code for `autoCompleteTextView` displays out the each list item in the `textview`

```
private val fooList: ArrayList<foo> = arrayListOf()  // Initializing for AutoCompleteTextView

// loading of data for AutoCompleteTextView
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {    
    val db = TestProjDB.getInstance(requireContext())
    fooList.addAll(db.fooDao().selectAllFromDb())
}

val adapter = ArrayAdapter(
    requireContext(), // Fragment context.
    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, // Layout
    fooList // Array
)
binding.Fragm1.setAdapter(adapter)
```

With this above code, when I type anything at all, the autocomplete provides suggestions as such:

```
foo(bar=001, far=sometext1)
foo(bar=002, far=sometext2)
foo(bar=003, far=sometext3)
foo(bar=004, far=sometext4)
```

**Question:**

1 - What do I need to do such that when I type, it provides suggestions in the format :

```
bar: 001
far: sometext1
bar: 002
far: sometext3
```

2 - I will also want it to be able to autocomplete via searching with `001` or `sometext` and the autocomplete provide the relevant results.

Comment: You should write a custom adapter with a custom filter. Just google it!

Comment: It's just a hack. Create a new `ArrayList` with generic type `String` and put add both the string and put in the new `ArrayList`like `( list.add(numberList.get(i) + ":" + textList.get(i)) )` and use this to make autocomplete.